# Not getting all the attribute for has_one serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have `User (name:string, email:string, admin_id:integer)` model and `admin_profile (id:integer, type:string, address:text, skills:string)` model

> User has_one admin_profile if admin_id is present.

Here is the serializer

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :email, :admin_id
  has_one :admin_profile, :if => :admin_id?
end
```

The problem is that I am only getting id and type when from the api when I render user. Is there a way to include all the admin_profile attributes in user if user is admin?

Comment: you may use `attributes :name, :email, :admin_profile` to include the `admin_profile`. If the User has no admin_profile, the entry `admin_profile` of the JSON response will remain empty

Comment: That worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment an answer for future reference:

You may use `attributes :name, :email, :admin_profile` to include the `admin_profile`. If the `User` has no `admin_profile`, the entry `admin_profile` of the JSON response will remain empty.

Note that a new feature just got merged, which does exactly what you wish:

```
has_one :admin_profile, if: :is_admin?
```

It is available in master, which will become RC4 very soon.